# Making an adjacency list of a given graph by reading the graph from a file

Tags: c, file, graph, linked-list, adjacency-list

***I am coding in `C` language.***

I have the following graph stored in the file named `graph_input.txt` :

```
7
2 4
1 3 4 6
2 6
1 2 6 5
4
4 2 3 7
6
```

where the 1st line gives the number of vertices in the graph and the consecutive lines give the vertices adjacent to the vertices 1,2,...,7 respectively i.e vertex 1 is adjacent to 2 and 4 and so on.

I want to read the file and make an adjacency list using array of linked lists. But I donot know how to detect the end of a line so that I can separate out the linked lists for each vertex. I have a littile knowledge about File Handling in C. All I know is some basic file operations and functions which I read from different sites in the internet. Initially I tried using `getw()` function to read the integers one by one but `getw()` is giving as output some wierd large numbers and not the integers in the given file. Then I used `fscanf` to read the integers one by one but now I cannot differentiate between newline and integers.

**My scheme** is to read the 1st line and store the number in a variable denoting the total number of vertices. Then I will declare an array of type `Node` which is a structure defined by me beforehand. Then for each element of the array, I will make a linked list of Nodes storing the vertices adjacent to that array index. But for that I need to be able to identify the newline at the end of each line read from the file graph_input.txt so that from the nextline I store the vertices in the next array index.

Please guide me doing this and suggest me any improvements in my scheme if needed.

Comment: You'll need to ask a more specific question than "guide me'. Please make an attempt, show your code as a [mre] and ask one specific thing related to the code.

Comment: Use `fgets` to get a line, then `strtok` to separate the line into pieces, and `atoi` or `strtol` to convert each piece.

Comment: @Dúthomhas For `fgets` I need to know the size of the line. Since it is a graph, the maximum number of adjacent vertices is (n- 1) , so if I use the delimiter single space then the string length for `fgets` should be (n-1+n-2), where n=total number of vertices. Am I correct?

Comment: No, since a vertex number may be multiple digits. Just assume a large number, like 1000. If you are working with truly large data then you will need to look to see if `fgets` returned a string ending with newline to see if the entire line was read.

Comment: @Esha _"For fgets I need to know the size of the line."_: yes, but just assume a reasonable maximum size like 5000 and that will probably be enough for 99.99% iof your use cases if not all.

Answer (score 0):

As per the many comments you could use `fgets` and then parse the result. If you don't want to take the risk of rejecting a file if a line is longer than a predefined maximum size, just switch to `getline`.

Another solution is to make use of `fscanf` limited parsing capabilities, to read an integer, then skipping spaces (you can add `\t` or anything else), and finally try reading a `\n`. If you manage to read a `\n`, the line is finished.

You can still distinguish why the parsing ended by inspecting the `fscanf` return code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *f = fopen("graph_input.txt", "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int nver;
    if (fscanf(f, "%d", &nver) == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nver; ++i) {
            // Read a list of vertices and dump it on stdout with commas
            int res;
            do {
                int idx;
                res = fscanf(f, "%d%*[ ]", &idx);
                if (res != 1) {
                    break;
                }
                printf("%d, ", idx);
                char newline[2];
                res = fscanf(f, "%[\n]", newline);
            } while (res == 0);
            if (res == -1) {
                printf("EOF found\n");
                break;
            }
            if (res == 0) {
                printf(" failed to read integer value\n");
                break;
            }
            if (res == 1) {
                printf("newline found\n");
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(f);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```